# Sketch 3 Plugin Changing Artboard Color

Tags: javascript, plugins, sketch-3, sketchapp, cocoascript

**So I can't seem to find the the method to change the color of the art board's background color.**

> This is what i have currently just missing the method to set the color.

```
var doc = context.document;
var artboard = MSArtboardGroup.new()
var artboardFrame = artboard.frame()

artboardFrame.setX(x)
artboardFrame.setY(y)
artboardFrame.setWidth(w)
artboardFrame.setHeight(h)

artboard.hasBackgroundColor = true;

doc.currentPage().addLayers([artboard])
```

This link to the sketch reference may help (didn't help me)
http://developer.sketchapp.com/reference/class/

Answer (score 1):

```
artboard.backgroundColor = MSColor.colorWithSVGString("#FFCC00");
```